Restore database problem when have two versions PostgreSQL version 13.14 and PostgreSQL 16
I have two PostgreSQL version installed 13.14 port 5432 and 16 port 5433
When I try to restore database on PostgreSQL 16 process failed

Restoring backup on the server 'PostgreSQL 16 (localhost:5433)'
Running command:
C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\13\bin\pg_restore.exe --host "localhost" --port "5433" --username "postgres"


pg_restore: error: unsupported version (1.15) in file header

BackUp of database is from PostgreSQL 16.
Please help me to solve this problem, I need to use two Postgres versions but I have problem restoring databases.

Use the pg_restore.exe from 16, not from 13. (so: C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\16\bin\pg_restore.exe

I se the problem but how to change this when I running restore from pgAdmin4 and PostgreSQL Binary Path default is PostgreSQL 16

find it under: Binary path in the pgAdmin preferences   (or start it from outside PgAdmin)

Because I use pgAdmin 4 from PostgreSQL version 16 when I want to make restore from pgAdmin just delete from PostgreSQL Binary Path  C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\13\bin and vice versa.
Maybe there is better sollution but this works to

I do see different paths for different versions, when looking at the preferences, see: https://i.sstatic.net/QXein.png
